# Azure load balancer with single VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've couple of VMs under same subnet in Azure without any availability set attached to any of the vm. When I try to use load balancer (public),it shows two options to load balance VMs

1. Availability set
2. Single VM

Is it necessary to use availability set to implement load balancer between VMs and they should be under same availability set?

Also ,if above it true, what is the purpose of single vm option where vm is visible to add under load balancer without any availability set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, it is. you cannot load balance 2 or more vm's that are not in the same availability set.
2. if you want NAT rules, for example, but makes very little sense anyway

Comment: Thanks,In another way is it possible to load balance two different region VMs as they will be in different availability set?

Comment: i honestly don't remember right now, but i imagine cross-region availability sets cannot exist

Comment: Thanks again.It should not be.I wanted to reconfirm this only.Since availability set  meaning of group of hardware.indicating all in same region.