# Attach Load Balancer to multiple VMs after machines are already created (Availability Set cannot be used in that case)

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, internal-load-balancer, azure-load-balancer

I created two VMs. I did not created Availability Set for them because I did not know I will need it. I do not want to re-create those VMs, since I needed one month to configure and install everything on them.

Now I created LB but I can see that I can associate it only to one VM or to Availability Set which will contain multiple VMs (which is as I stated not possible because it can be configured only during the creation of VM).

I try to associate LB to VM but I can see that I can select only one VM.

I cannot believe that I cannot select at least two VMs for LB??? Is this really working in this way?? This is really surprising for me and very disappointing.

Please suggest me if there is some quick work around how to associate Load Balancer with same resource group and virtual network to multiple VMs.

Please! 
Is there really not any kind of work around for this?  I checked this and it was not mentioned how to associate multiple VMs.
[Azure load balancer with single VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577592/azure-load-balancer-with-single-vm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard load balancer (you would need to attach standard public ips to the vms). The only way to make it work without Availability Set. Thats how it is in Azure, sadly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-standard-overview

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for response. My machines already have public IPs that is OK. Can you please tell me where is that Standard LB  creation - in which section? I can only see : Create a zone redundant Public Standard Load Balancer
Create a zonal Public Standard Load Balancer, 
Create Basic Load Balancer. I am not sure what kind of creation I should start. Please provide me more details, so I can have a clear picture. Thanks

Comment: it depends on if you need an external one, or internal one. if you need an external one use `Public Standard Load Balancer`, you can probably figure out the internal one ;)

Comment: I do not need external one. Because it is for the internal service which is used currently only on one machine, and only internal application is invoking that service so instead of the VM01 IP  I would need to set LoadBalancing IP. Can you tell me now which instruction link should I use from Microsoft site?? Also I am not sure if I should use Public or Private ip address? Will my Standard LB have both of them? Sorry for lot of questions but have not worked before with this. Thanks

Comment: when creating a load balancer pick type: internal, sku standard.i was unable to find the instruction, this one is pretty close, just use internal, not external. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/quickstart-load-balancer-standard-public-portal everything else is almost the same

Comment: Hi. I selected Standard option for LB. My VMs do have Public IP addresses but they have SKU set to Basic (not Standard). When I go to LB option to add Backend pool  It seems that I cannot select my VMs for this Load Balancer. Do they need to have Standard Public IPs?  Thank you

Comment: yes, like i said, they need standard public ips for this to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182031/discussion-between-dejan-and-4c74356b41).